# Асинхронная работа бота Discord с несколькими пользователями сразу

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Столкнулся с проблемой. Пишу бота, который работает с DM каналом пользователей.

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from config import settings


intents = disnake.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'], intents = intents )



class step1(disnake.ui.View):
    
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple,label='Player info')
    async def one1 (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await msg.edit('PlayerINFO',view=playerinfo())


    
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple,label='Guild')
    async def two1 (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await interaction.channel.send('Guild Info:test')
        
    


    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple,label='Quest')
    async def three1 (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await interaction.channel.send('Quest Info:test')


    
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple,label='Report')
    async def four1 (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await interaction.channel.send('Report:test')

class playerinfo(disnake.ui.View):
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple,label='Check')
    async def one1 (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await interaction.channel.send('Check')
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple,label='Write')
    async def two1 (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await interaction.channel.send('Check')
    @disnake.ui.button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.blurple,label='Back')
    async def three1 (self,button:disnake.Button,interaction:disnake.Interaction):
        await msg.edit("Menu",view=step1())
    
        
        
    
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    global msg
    msg = await ctx.reply("Menu",view=step1())
    print("test")

bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Собственно, проблема в том, что при использовании команды "/button" или переходе на разные уровни меню(как пример, playerinfo) несколькими пользователями приводит к тому, что бот не реагирует на команды всех пользователей, кроме последнего.